# Can I disable Nagle on `QNetworkAccessManager` requests?

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

We are using the `QNetworkAccessManager` for our http/s requests. Some details for the request can be set via `QSslConfiguration`.

Unfortunately I cannot use the `LowDelayOption` (or I do not know how).

`QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption`

> Try to optimize the socket for low latency. For a QTcpSocket this would set the TCP_NODELAY option and disable Nagle's algorithm. Set this to 1 to enable.

Can I somehow use "no nagle" (low latency) with the `QNetworkAccessManager`?

Comment: Looks like it is not possible without subclassing `QNetworkAccessManager` and something more. Try [`QNetworkRequest::DoNotBufferUploadDataAttribute`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#Attribute-enum). You can also disable Nagle's algorithm in your OS settings.

Comment: Subclassing is an option, need to check.
Disabling on OS level: I am not sure about whether this would not have any side effects.

Comment: ...But unfortunately the classes are not ready to sublassing. As I can see, Qt Network access module has so complicated code that it looks almost impossible.

Comment: See comments in the `QHttpNetworkConnectionChannel::_q_connected()` method sources